# Reordering UICollectionView in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to build a UICollectionView, or use something similar library to make grid view, in which i can rearrange cells. My app supports iOS 7, and, unfortunately `UICollectionView` method - `(BOOL)beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
is only available on iOS 9 and later.

Is there any way i can achieve the effect of 'drag and reorder' collection view cells on iOS7? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I happened to come across the very same issue, so let me add my two cents on this.

In order to achieve to get the same effect of what UIKit does when rearranging cells, I followed a more or less similar approach described below:

1. Add a long-press gesture recognizer into collection view so that
   you’d be able to detect which cell was tapped without messing up
   with `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method.
2. When user long-presses on a cell, take a screenshot of that cell, add the snapshot view into collection view and then hide the cell. As the user moves his finger on the screen, update the snapshot’s center to move it programmatically so it will look like the user is dragging the cell.
3. The trick is to decide when and how to swap cells. As the snapshot moves around, it will intersect with other cells. When it happens, you should update your data source and call `moveItemAtIndexPath` so it will swap the positions of original cell and the cell which the snapshot intersects.
4. When dragging ends, remove the snapshot from collection view and show the original cell.

You can map those steps to gesture recognizer’s states, so that we know what you should do at each state:

- **Began**: 1
- **Changed**: 2, 3
- **Ended**, **Cancelled**, **Failed**: 4

I put an [example project](https://github.com/ozgur/MovingCells) in my github account, so you can download and play around with it. Here, I will just implement the gesture callback:

*Note: The below code may not work because I threw away some implementation specific details. But it should show the basic intent. Please download the full code from my github repo.*

```
func longPressRecognized(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
  let location = recognizer.locationInView(collectionView)
  let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(location)

  switch recognizer.state {
    case .Began:
      let cell = collectionView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
      let snapshotView = cell.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
      snapshot.center = cell.center
      collectionView.addSubview(snapshotView)
      cell.contentView.alpha = 0.0 // hides original cell

    case .Changed:
      snapshotView.center = location // will follow user's finger.      
      dataSource.swap(originalCellIndexPath.item, indexPath.item) // swaps data
      collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(originalCellIndexPath, toIndexPath: indexPath) // swaps cells
      originalCellIndexPath = indexPath

    default:
      let cell = cellForRowAtIndexPath(originalCellIndexPath)
      cell.contentView.alpha = 1.0
      snapshotView.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

Here is the effect you will get *(recorded on iOS 8.4 Simulator)*:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! I did accomplish that by adding https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout to project.

Comment: this seems will not work good if you don't add

 
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    ...
}

Comment: @RemembranceNN what do you mean by "seems will not work good"? Can you briefly describe what kind of issue you are experiencing?

Comment: @ozgur for me on iOS 11 & Objective C it was not working at all until I overrided function moveItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Works as Excepted.